# In an Atom feed is it ok to change the "updated" field when an entry has its content changed?

Tags: xml, atom-feed

If an Entry represents some file/resource that has changed - is it enough to change the updated field? I note that most feed readers won't show it as "new" as it has the same UUID?

[RFC 4287](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) says that I can change it, but feed readers seem to ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from looking at this, RFC 4287 says it's fine to update a resource and its updated field. However, if you want feed readers to pick it up as a fresh item - you need to think of an Entry representing a change, not so much 1 to 1 with an underlying resource.